# Android app can't submit on Samsung Galaxy Apps (how to include Samsung SDK?)

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, samsung-mobile-sdk, samsung-galaxy

The Samsung Galaxy Apps store is not accepting my app for submission.

There is a category section where there are two fields for selecting a category, I have set the both to Main Category but when I submit it states that I still need to select a category for my app.  If I select the only other option for one of those category fields (that option being GALAXY Specials), I'm provided with sub-categories (of which I must choose otherwise I still get the no category selected error on submitting).

No matter what sub-category I choose I always get the following error:

```
The registered binaries do not meet the category conditions for Galaxy Specials.
The Galaxy Specials category can be selected only if at least one binary supports Galaxy Specials.
You can go to ‘Binary>Advanced Mode>Binary Details’ to check the supported Galaxy Specials options.
```

I've done some digging around and hear that the only way to get passed this issue is include the Samsung SDK in my Binary.

My Question is:

- How do I include the Samsung SDK in my Binary?  (I have already downloaded it via the SDK Manager using the User Defined Add-on Site "http://developer.samsung.com/sdk-manager/repository/Samsung-SDK.xml")
- Otherwise, is there another way of getting my app to submit?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have just came across this issue and managed to fix it. From the thread below, we can read what Samsung has told one of the users (https://www.scirra.com/forum/samsung-appstore-publishing_t116364):

> Also, please note that -If the following user-permission exists in the
>   manifest file, it is considered that the application uses Samsung
>   Developer SDK.
>   * < uses-permission android:name="com.samsung.android.providers.context.permission.WRITE_USE_APP_FEATURE_SURVEY"
>   / >
>   -If the user-permission does not exist in the manifest file, it is considered that the application does not use the Samsung Developer
>   SDK.

Therefore, just add this to your Android's Manifest.xml and you are rebuild your apk.

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.samsung.android.providers.context.permission.WRITE_USE_APP_FEATURE_SURVEY"/>
```

Once rebuilt, upload the new apk to the http://seller.samsungapps.com/ site.

You will see the Samsung Developer SDK being recognised even though you did not use it in your app besides putting the line in the manifest.

[image]

You may now submit your app successfully.